# AccessVBAでSharePointリストのリンクテーブルからルックアップ列の値を取得したい

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint

---

SharePointリストに[User]と[History]リストを作成しました。

**[User]**
列1 AccountID
列2 MailAddress

**[History]**
列1 AccountID
列2 AccountID:MailAddress
列3 WorkData

[History]の列1は[User]のAccountIDのルックアップ列です。[History]の列2は列1のルックアップ結果のMailAddressが表示されています。

以下のレコードを1つずつ挿入します。

**[User]**
AccountID = 2
MailAddress = 'xxx.com'

**[History]**
AccountID = 2
AccountID:MailAddress = 'xxx.com'
WorkData = 'OK'

---

Accessに[History]のリンクテーブル[History]を作成し、DAO.Recordsetで値を取得しました。

```
Dim db as DAO.Database
Dim rs as DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDB
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("History")
Debug.Print rs.Fields("AccountID").Value
```

[User]のAccountID列の値[2]が取得されることを期待していたのですが、SharePointリストのシステム列であるIDの値が取得されてしまいます。

・システム列であるIDをインデックス列として使用したくない。
・SharePointリストにAccountID:AccountID列を作成したくない。

以上の理由からAccessVBAで[History]のルックアップ列AccountIDから直接[User]のAccountIDの値を取得したいのですが、方法はありますでしょうか？